# CSS Select Children in the same Class Name

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML which users will enter.  My job is to select "mychild" class names and style different colors for each mychild.

Problem: I use `first-of-type` or `nth-of-type()` (I did use `first-chil`, too) they all don't work out.  So that `first-of-type`, `nth-of-type()` or `first-chil` are not a solution.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m97spu5y/)

```css
.parent .mychild:first-of-type {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: yellow;
}

.parent .mychild:nth-of-type(2) {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: red;
}

.parent .mychild:nth-of-type(3) {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other">Child</div>
  <div class="other">Child</div>
  <div class="mychild">Child</div>
  <div class="other">Child</div>
  <div class="other">Child</div>
  <div class="mychild">Child</div>
  <div class="other">Child</div>
  <div class="other">Child</div>
  <div class="mychild">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Andrei Gheorghiu, can you please remove "Duplicate"?  because my question is completely different.  Thanks

Comment: @abcidd Your question is unclear as to what your requirements are, so this would not be reopen-worthy (as it would just get re-closed as unclear). For example, will your markup always look like this or will there be eventually a 4th or 5th `myChild`? What about the `other` children in between; will there always be two? At any rate, I have found an actual appropriate dupe and adjusted the banner to show that one, instead.